# On quotients of unipotent subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I have some issues visualizing how to compute quotient of subgroups in general, safe making explicit the cosets which is not really satisfactory nor geometrically meaningful.

**Here is a specific instance.** Let $k$ and $K$ two fields, $K$ extending $k$. This could also be rings, like $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$ Consider $GL(2)$ and its unipotent subgroup
$$U = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & *\\ & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \subset GL(2)$$

I want to compute $U(K) / U(k)$. This is easy because of the identification of $U$ with the multiplicative subgroup, giving a quotient isomorphic to $K/k$. However, this example is too particular.

**Another instance.** Consider the similar question in $GL(3)$ now. An take the unipotent subgroup
$$U_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & \alpha x & \beta y \\ & 1 & \gamma z \\ & & 1 \end{matrix} \right)_{\{x, y, z \in k\}} \subset GL(2, k)$$

for fixed $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in k$, and also the whole unipotent subgroup
$$U = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & * & * \\ & 1 & * \\ & & 1 \end{matrix} \right)_{\{x, y, z \in K\}} \subset GL(3, K)$$

> How do I compute the quotient $U / U_1$? (even in the case $k=K$)

Indeed in this case, there is no obvious identification with product of simple multiplicative groups.

Comment: I am confused by your definition of $U_1$. What are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$?

Comment: In your first example, $U(K)/U(k) $ is isomorphic to $(K,+)/(k,+)$, not $K^*/k^*$. Also your $U_1$ in your second example  is not a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,k)$. And in that case $U_1$ is not normal in $U$ when $K \ne k$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, they are fixed constants in $k$!

Comment: @DerekHolt I corrected in the question, and anyway I want to compute a quotient, not particularly seeking a group at the end. These are mostly appearing in integral or analytical computations.